# Create document in Lotus Domino database via perl script

Tags: php, perl, e-commerce, http-post, lotus-domino

I've seen blocks of code like this

```
use Win32::OLE; 
my $Notes = Win32::OLE->new('Notes.NotesSession') 
    or die "Cannot start Lotus Notes Session object.\n"; 
my $database = $Notes->GetDatabase("",'mail\VIMM.nsf');
```

but my script is running on a virtual webfusion apache service so how do you establish a connection to database on my domino server, I have control of its acl and its a website so can pass in a username & password. The script & 'POST' data is sent by a third party gateway with results of the transaction (Success/ Fail + name value pairs etc) which I need to capture. I can't do it directly on the domino server because although Domino supports PERL scripts, they will only work if PERL is also installed on the server which isn't an option.

Comment: So your issue is that you do not have Lotus Notes running on the same server as the perl script? Domino is also a web application server so you can communicate with the server using HTTP from your perl script.

Comment: Yes that is my issue. You can have a Perl script on a Domino server communicate with Domino but only if you have Perl installed on the server as an independant program. You put the Perl scripts inside the Domino folder structure so they can be protected by Domino but it doesn't have embedded Perl interpreter like it does for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem is that a url such as **http://www.mysite.com/thankyou?orderno=123** won't work in a Lotus Domino website because the ? is a special character (eg ?openagent, ?opendatabase) to the Domino web engine. You also can't use **http://www.mysite.com/(thankyou)?openagent?orderno=456** (I tried), in both cases all you get is 404 page not found error and a domino log error "don't understand the url". The question was originally asking for help with Perl to solve the problem but I couldn't Perl scripts to run on my webfusion community server but fortunately quickly had success with this simple php script:

```
<?php
    $params = "";
    $url = "http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/";
    $path = "wpx/website.nsf/httpagent?openagent";
      if($_GET) {
    $kv = array();
          foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
              $kv[] = "$key=$value";
          }
          $params = join("&", $kv);
}
print "<script>window.location.href=\"" . $url . $path . "&" . $params . "\"</script>";
?>
```

The script is placed on my webfusion server under a subdomain which effectively translates the url into a format that Domino can handle, the format ?openagent&orderno=456 is easily handled by either a java or Lotusscript agent, the parameter is extracted from the CGI Request_Content field.

The redirect means I don't for now need to manipulate data in the domino database directly, it also means that with the exception of the url translation script all the website code is in the domino database.

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Domino is also a web application server so you can communicate with the server using HTTP (GET and POST) from your perl script on the Apache server.

This might require changes to the Domino application in question in order for it to serve the content you expect.

Comment: The content I'm trying to deal with is actually a post to my website from a third party so I have no influence on what is coming in, it arrives with ?oid=nnnn appended to the URL which Domino can't process. I'm trying to write some perl to grab the 'POST' data and pass it onto the domino server in a format it can handle

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can provide a WebService on your Domino Server.

Comment: Sorry don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

For OLE/COM to work, Perl and the script have to be located on a server where Notes and/or Domino are installed. Otherwise, the OLE/COM classes are not installed and not available.

As Per and Klaus mentioned, if you can't put Notes/Domino on the machine with Perl on it, you have to switch to some sort of webbased communication.

Comment: I was looking for an alternative to the "use win32::OLE" which will also only work if your running the server on a Windows server, irrespective of Perl being installed.

Comment: I'm also hosting my Domino applications with Bluesky & Prominic on a shared server basis and until I can afford/ justify my own servers can't control the underlying operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to COM/OLE, you could use the [IBM Lotus Domino Data Service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service), which is new in Domino Designer 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack 1:

> The IBM® Lotus® Domino® Data Service is a REST API that accesses
>   databases on Domino servers. It is part of Domino Access Services.
>
> The Domino Data Service receives requests and sends responses using
>   HTTP and HTTPS protocols with body content in JSON format.
>
> The Domino Data Service allows you to obtain information on databases,
>   views, folders, and documents. You can update, add, and delete
>   documents.

Comment: The problem was not manipulating data in the database, that's fairly easy using authenticated http POSTs processed by agents in the database, more importantly I'm on a shared server so don't have super admin rights, Bluesky are great but they aren't going to allow me to play with extra services on a production grade server that hosts other customers applications & mail.